# "Unknown Error" returned from Microsoft Graph API when getting to-do task lists

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I was trying to create some to-do tasks through Microsoft graph API. By following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman, now I can GET my profile by `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, the response looks fine.

However, when I tried to get my todo lists by `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/todo/lists`, it's giving me 401 Unauthorized code and "Unknown Error". I've confirmed that I have delegated permissions `Tasks.Read`, `Tasks.ReadWrite`, `User.Read` as well as corresponding application permissions. I've doubled confirmed this both in Azure portal and through decoding the access token I've got in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms).

The scope from access code is:

`"scp": "Mail.Read Notes.Create Notes.Read Notes.Read.All Notes.ReadWrite Notes.ReadWrite.All Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp Tasks.Read Tasks.ReadWrite User.Read profile openid email",`

I've tried to change a different account, but the problem still exists.

I've tried to copy paste the access token from Microsoft Graph Explorer, that token works perfectly but there's no document about how to get that kind of token.

Comment: If you are using the application permissions then "Tasks.ReadWrite.All" permission is also required :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todo-list-lists?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: @MehtabSiddique I'm aware of that, but in my case, I'm trying to go through delegated permission flow.

Comment: using [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to generate the access token